# How do I use enums without repeating the enum name again and again?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code like:

```
PokerHand hand = new(PokerCard.HeartAce, PokerCard.HeartKing, PokerCard.HeartQueen,
                     PokerCard.HeartJack, PokerCard.HeartTen);
```

where `PokerCard` is defined as:

```
public enum PokerCard : int
{
    SpadeAce = 1, SpadeTwo = 2, SpadeThree = 3, SpadeFour = 4, SpadeFive = 5,...
}
```

Can I do something like:

```
with (PokerCard) {
  PokerHand hand = new(HeartAce, HeartKing, HeartQueen, HeartJack, HeartTen);
}
```

in C#/ASP.NET?

Comment: No, you can't. See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/764

Comment: That said, an enum holding every possible playing card is unusual. Normally people go with a struct containing `(Suit, Number)`. If you want to, you can then start writing things like `Card.Hearts(10)`. If you `using static Card`, you can shorten that to e.g. `Hearts(10)`

Comment: Well this is for writing unit test to create hands. That's a good idea, thank you.

Comment: Why is everyone saying you can't do this? You can't do the specific pseudo-code he shows, but you can achieve his intent by statically using the class: i.e. add the following to your using block at the top of your cs file: `using static My.Namespace.PokerCard`.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should. Anyone looking at your code after you've done this is going to be very confused as to what the hell you've done and why. Just leave it alone...

Comment: @RB. because sometimes people are wrong :)

Comment: @Liam I disagree. I think if you're enums are not going to conflict or cause confusion with anything else in your program (and `HeartTen` is pretty obvious what it is), then statically using the enum is fine. Other examples of times you might statically import an enum are enums of colors, or HTTP status codes: `if (response.Status == NotFound)` is nicer than `if (response.Status == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)` IMO.

Comment: Why would you define your hand at compile time anyway? Surely you'd pull random values out of the collection returned by Enum.GetValues? Edit: just saw the test note/reason for a fixed hand..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Won't say it's a good idea, but you can do that with using static directive (C# 6.0+ I think):

```
using static ConsoleApp4.PokerCard;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            PokerHand hand = new(HeartAce, HeartKing);
        }
    }

    public enum PokerCard {
        HeartAce,
        HeartKing
    }

    public class PokerHand {
        public PokerHand(PokerCard a, PokerCard b) {

        }
    }
}
```

`using static <enum>` allows to refer to enum members without specifying enum type.

Comment: great answer, especially the "Won't say it's a good idea" :)

Answer (score 2):

It's rare to have every possible card defined in an enum. People normally define a struct which contains both the value and a suit.

```
public enum Suit
{
    Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades
}

public struct Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; }
    public int Value { get; }
    
    public Card(Suit suit, int value)
    {
        // Aces are high
        if (value < 1 || value > 14)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), "Must be between 1 and 14");
        
        Suit = suit;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This lets you create a card using e.g:

```
var card = new Card(Suit.Spades, 3);
```

That's still a bit wordy, so we can create some helper methods:

```
public struct Card
{
    // ...

    public static Card Club(int value) => new Card(Suit.Clubs, value);
    public static Card Diamond(int value) => new Card(Suit.Diamonds, value);
    public static Card Heart(int value) => new Card(Suit.Hearts, value);
    public static Card Spade(int value) => new Card(Suit.Spades, value);
}
```

This lets us write:

```
var card = Card.Club(3);
```

If we then do:

```
using static Card;
```

We can write:

```
var card = Club(3);
```

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUPgAwAE+xAbDQMITIYDcFFAbmzQGM2GGgF4WAG1TAAFMSoBKLuQr4AzDQCmMVGBoBlVFAQUA3hRqXJ0gM5waAESgQwAexgY7NABKa2CL30ABwgMTRsKAF9uSg0bBDQBBBZhMwsrdQMjZMNjGlMaAHNNBA4aaPIrOg1YZIA1CClNfKKSsoqq9MtM1nYZXOSbbPtamj4mhS78qaqAelmaAEEBcJo2ZoALKEKNmasoADMaGXHUZoAeGmIaXFwxxrOaAD4rgBZJyqqvywQN5FcAO40GCaIGLZCFXTaBAAeVQsIOACUIDBigBRAAeKyCCCg7hkMBcmlcBxOD00CnsACIALKoeI0YDNJkIAGabRXNYeN5UpR7Sz8rJ5cRDYzKb6WBpNMT3JriqwdKxTTL0Ji9ETMKSyUanCliF4goHq/rZAB0mts9l1fM+3Q0qpS7EczjcHhkOvJCn1wNBjowJuMpqcLncnitnvldrojD9Pj8yAQ7pgyWt3sNfoDCFNvn8Xmtkeq0bVwgMITCSZTnrTvuNA1NwVC4XDE2UFQoQA).

Comment: I agree this is a better way and I will change to use like this, but Evk's answer is actually answering the question so I'll accept that.

Comment: That's fair: Evk got an upvote from me

Answer (score 1):

Answer: (edited) You can apparently, but I don't think you should...

If you just want to type fewer characters, you can create an alias.

```cs
using PC = PokerCard;

PokerHand hand = new(PC.HeartAce, PC.HeartKing, PC.HeartQueen,
                     PC.HeartJack, PC.HeartTen);
```

Comment: I get CS0119 for this syntax. Is it avaiable for a `public enum PokerCard`?

Comment: except you totally can; see @Evk's answer

Comment: You have to put the using statement at the top with other usings. If that doesn't fix the issue, then I'd need to see more code to help.

Comment: Fixed with the correct location.